# I have a situation with showing 24 random images, then matching to a database

Tags: mysql, image, random

basically I have some code that displays 24 random images from a directory, then each time a user refreshes the web page it will shuffle each time. I have got that, but then I've got my database with a table called images with 3 columns "id, imagename and price".

Then I need to pretty much put in some code like - if ($row['imagename'] == $randompic){ print $row['imagename'].'
'.$row['price'] } else { print ":("; }

Before hand I put in $randompic = getrandompic2($picsdir, $num_imgs_to_show); which is the function that prints out the random images.. But currently I am experiencing issues with this. Basically it is printing out the 24 random images 2 times and outputting ":("... PLEASE HELP!!!

CODE ---------

```
$picsdir = "images"; 

function getrandompic2($picsdir,$num_imgs) { 

    //chdir("."); 

    $clips = array(); 
    $dir = opendir($picsdir); 

    while ($f = readdir($dir)) { 
        $ext = substr($f,-4); 
//          if($ext == ".JPG" || $ext == ".jpg") { 
        if($ext == ".jpg") { 
            $clips[] = $picsdir . "/" . $f;          
        } 
        $numfiles++; 
    } 
    closedir($dir); 

//==$randpic = $clips[$p]; 
    $numbers = $clips; 
    $x = 0;  //counter for limit images 
    srand((float)microtime() * 1000000); 
    shuffle($numbers); 
    while (list(, $number) = each($numbers)) { 
      if ($x >= $num_imgs) return; 
        echo "<img src=" . "$number " . ">"; 
      $x++; 
  } 
} 
  $num_imgs_to_show = 24; 
  $randompic = getrandompic2($picsdir, $num_imgs_to_show);

?>
<table width="40%">
    <th width="10%">
<?php


//execute the SQL query and return records
$result = mysql_query("SELECT imagename, price FROM images");

//fetch tha data from the database 
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
   echo "ImageName:".$row{'imagename'}."<br>Price:".$row{'price'}."<br>";

if ($row['imagename'] == $randompic){
    print ':D';
    print $row['imagename'];
}
    else    {
    print ':(';
    }

}

  print getrandompic2($picsdir, $num_imgs_to_show) . "<br/ >"; 


?>
</th>
</table>
```